# "No result object given - no result to handle" logger:"org.springframework.transaction.event.TransactionalApplicationListenerMethodAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, microservices

So in my spring boot application,I'm having 5 listener's and return type is void. All 5 listener annotated with **@TransactionalEventListener(fallbackExecution=true)**
All these 5 listener consumes the messages but first it will print this log message
**"No result object given - no result to handle" logger:"org.springframework.transaction.event.TransactionalApplicationListenerMethodAdapter**
and then it start with actuall listener logic.
I'm facing this issue only in the lower environment

**"message":"No result object given - no result to handle","logger_name":"org.springframework.transaction.event.TransactionalApplicationListenerMethodAdapter"**

I tried to restart the server,  but nothing works

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide some information about Spring version, application properties and maybe some logs...